# How to add values from given dataset into empty dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

- Below code copyrighted by Datacamp from Python course exercise that I am taking.
- I have been given a csv file and The dataset contains Twitter data and I had to iterate over entries in a column to build a dictionary in which the keys are the names of languages and the values are the number of tweets in the given language. The resulting code is correct and working. **However** , I cannot quite understand how code works in the if-else statement part.
- The output of the code is:  `{'en': 97, 'et': 1, 'und': 2}`
- **My question is:** How can we get the given output above. What happens exactly inside the code in for loop and if-else.

```
# Import pandas
import pandas as pd 

# Import Twitter data as DataFrame: df
df = pd.read_csv('tweets.csv') 

# Initialize an empty dictionary: langs_count
langs_count = {}

# Extract column from DataFrame: col
col = df['lang']

# Iterate over lang column in DataFrame
for entry in col:

    # If the language is in langs_count, add 1 
    if entry in langs_count.keys():
        langs_count[entry] += 1
    # Else add the language to langs_count, set the value to 1
    else:
        langs_count[entry] = 1

# Print the populated dictionary
print(langs_count)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some explanatory notes in the `for | if | else` to improve the understanding of the code as requested.

I changed the dataset to a minimum example, for the simplicity to explain.

As a general tip: Pandas has a built-in method (`value_counts`) that does the same.

```
# Import pandas
import pandas as pd 

# Import Twitter data as DataFrame: df
# df = pd.read_csv('tweets.csv') 
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
          'en',  # 1st row
          'en',  # 2nd row
          'und', # 3rd row
          'et',  # 4th row
          'und'  # 5th row
          ],
    columns=['lang']
)

# Initialize an empty dictionary: langs_count
langs_count = {}

# Extract column from DataFrame: col
col = df['lang']

print('before the loop, langs_count is an empty dict')
print(langs_count, '\n')
# Iterate over lang column in DataFrame
for ii, entry in enumerate(col):

    # If the language is in langs_count, add 1 
    if entry in langs_count.keys():
        print(f'{ii}\nif: the key "{col.iloc[ii]}" exists, so adds 1 to value')
        langs_count[entry] += 1
    # Else add the language to langs_count, set the value to 1
    else:
        print(f'{ii}\nelse: the key "{col.iloc[ii]}" does not exist, so create it with value 1')
        langs_count[entry] = 1
    print(langs_count, '\n')

# Print the populated dictionary
# print(langs_count)
#{'en': 97, 'et': 1, 'und': 2}

# the same could be reached through
# without the need of loop or if / else
print('value_counts solution')
df['lang'].value_counts().to_dict()
```

Out:

```
"""
before the loop, langs_count is an empty dict
{} 

0
else: the key "en" does not exist, so create it with value 1
{'en': 1} 

1
if: the key "en" exists, so adds 1 to value
{'en': 2} 

2
else: the key "und" does not exist, so create it with value 1
{'en': 2, 'und': 1} 

3
else: the key "et" does not exist, so create it with value 1
{'en': 2, 'und': 1, 'et': 1} 

4
if: the key "und" exists, so adds 1 to value
{'en': 2, 'und': 2, 'et': 1} 

value_counts solution
{'en': 2, 'et': 1, 'und': 2}
"""
```

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation and the extra knowledge you added. It was very useful!